# DCOM/IIS Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-6, dcom, opc

This is my first time dealing with IIS and DCOM so I apologize if I am butchering terminology:

I am trying to develop an Intranet web site and I am having fits with what I think is a permissions issue. There is a function called from a DLL referenced in the web application that reads data from several DCOM applications on the web server.

When I run the web application in the Visual Studio debugger on another computer on the network, it reads successfully. If I put the same DLL and function calls in an EXE and run it on any machine on the network, it reads successfully. I thought everything was good to go.

**However**, when I deploy the web site in IIS, it throws an exception when reading from only one of the DCOM applications. The other ones read successfully.

The run identity for the non-working application is shown as "The launching user" in DCOM config, while the working ones are tied to domain accounts. These are legacy applications and I cannot easily modify run identities or access permissions.

I'm guessing it has to do with the user name the IIS process is running under -- I know the Visual Studio debugger and the test EXE all run under my Windows AD credentials (which have fairly extensive privileges) when I call them, but I don't know what credentials IIS is working with.

Does anyone have suggestions on what the problem is (and how best to address it)? I want to make sure I'm heading in the right direction before I start asking for permission to modify DCOM configurations or IIS settings, neither of which I know anything about.

Comment: You can change the identity of the application pool under which your site is running to the same user name where the OPC  server is running

Comment: The comment above is right. Each Web application belongs to one IIS app pool. If you have more Web applications under IIS, you will probably need to tweak just this one, and in such case you should create a new app pool just for it, and set its identity accordingly. On the other hand, while I understand that you want to stay away from changing the DCOM config, in most cases it would be better to change "The launching user" on the DCOM app itself to a specific account. "The launching user" can cause it to be run multiple times under different identities, which is rarely intended.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think this is the correct way to go -- I'll just have to see how to go about getting permission to make the recommended changes. I'll run the app pool and DCOM app under the same, domain-linked identity and hopefully that will fix the problem.
Thank you for your help!